# How to use multiple IN(array) in a row

Tags: mysql

Mysql selects all case from three IN() i need to select only: 3, 204, 68 | 3, 204, 69 | 49, 230, 2 | 49, 230, 3

```
SELECT * FROM rates r
WHERE 1 = 1
AND r.active = 1
AND r.client_id IN (3,3,49,49)
AND r.mcc       IN (204,204,230,230)
AND r.mnc       IN (68,69,2,3)
```

Not like that :

[image]

How to get like this: `client_id = 3 AND mcc = 204 AND mnc = 68` also  `client_id = 3 AND mcc = 204 AND mnc = 69`
thai is all for client_id = 3

Answer (score 0):

This would work, but it is specifically for the data you gave me, you'd have to generate the query if you want it to work dynamically:

```
SELECT *
FROM rates r
WHERE 1 = 1
AND r.active = 1
AND ((r.client_id = 3 AND r.mcc = 204 AND r.mnc = 68)
     OR (r.client_id = 3 AND r.mcc = 204 AND r.mnc = 69)
     OR (r.client_id = 49 AND r.mcc = 230 AND r.mnc = 2)
     OR (r.client_id = 49 AND r.mcc = 230 AND r.mnc = 3))
```

Comment: i got some solution to convert my massives into one massive with strings items ['3-204-68'],[ but i don't undrstand how can i use that

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic combination of AND and OR, without any IN

```
SELECT *
FROM
rates r

WHERE
1 = 1
AND r.active                               = 1
AND ((r.client_id = 3 AND r.mcc = 204 AND r.mnc = 68) OR (r.client ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Using "concat_ws"

```
SELECT * FROM rates r
    WHERE active = 1
    AND concat_ws(",", r.client_id, r.mcc, r.mnc) IN
        ("3,204,68", "3,204,69", "49,230,2", "49,230,3")
```